# How can solve fogs,lights problem with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

[image]I'm learning some tutorials that is industrial background.
I know this tutorial is focused on Eevee system. but I want to get a better quality of scene. that's why I want to use Cycles, but there are some problems such as lights, fogs
those pictures are including lights,fogs that I learned from the tutorials. yes it's very worked in Eevee, the lights has blur, the fog is staying at the background obviously, but the Cycles version doesn't work, How can I solve this problems? I want to have blur lights, fogs in my scene

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eevee, there is a feature called bloom you are using. But unfortunatley cycles doesn't have such an option , unless you use compositing. I recommend you watch some compositing tutorials on making lights glow in cycles. Here is the short summary of the process: select the objects you are using as a light, and then go to object properties: pass index to 2 on all of them (Remeber to set it to two on all the objects that have emmision shaders or are covering a lamp underneathe.).[image] Then in the render layers tab enable object index (Make sure you are in cycles to find this option.).[image] Then render your image, switch to the compositing tab, and follow the compositing setup in the image below.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, plus Do you have an information about fogs?, I'd like to know in cycles like Eevee picture

Comment: I mean, as you can see the first picture, you can see foggy feelings. I want to get this feelings and adjust in Cycles

Comment: @HyeonJEONG If you want to use volumetrics, you can but in the eevee picture it is the effect of bloom, so I say you go to the render layers tab and then enable emit. After that render your image again and in the compositor instead of using the ID Mask as the image input for the blur node, use emit. Then play with the blur and mix node settings a bit. This way also might not work.

Comment: @HyeonJEONG You can see compositing tutorials about how to add mist in blender, or maybe watch some tutorials on volumetrics rendering in cycles.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will try it, and thank you!

Comment: You're Welcome (!