# cycles emissive material not baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

hi i am trying to bake everything to than import in Threejs, my initial goal was to have the same looks as i have in Evee render, but Evee doesn't support baking , so i  have to go with cycles, tree material doesn't even render in cycles and when i try to bake it i just get black texture. can anyone help me out with the whole baking thing?
here is link to [project](https://www.mediafire.com/file/8jtiv3gyejf9bhg/123.blend/file)
[image]

note: black are leaves of tree, and other baked parts are branches.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can solve fogs,lights problem with Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224536/how-can-solve-fogs-lights-problem-with-cycles)

Comment: bloom is only one aspect of the problem and ill be honest i dont know how its possible to bake it so probably i don't even need that, got to solve more important problems

Comment: You could bake the "Emission" in cycles and do some post processing to make it glow. Cycles doesn't glow by default.

Comment: i udnerstand that but i have problem baking emission aswell as you can see in first image left bottom side\

Comment: Maybe don't do "combined", do emission only? That way you will get a separate emission map.

Comment: could try that but in the end i need combined baked image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Baked Blacks

By opening your "project" file (you share with us), you use  *Color Ramp* node set Pink(left side) > Black(right side) that works just fine for me.

On other hand in your screen the *Color Ramp* node is set Black-Pink ... this setup generates black in all bake.

The problem lies in your *Layer Weight* node. This node can't be handled by bake as intended, because the factor is considering face normal direction (angle) pointed to camera view. For baker all faces are calculated as front view. When ColorRamp is set from Pink to Black. First color(Pink) is taken as color assigned to normal pointed to camera (front). So if you want bake pink emission, keep Pink at Left.

Just to be clear, you can't bake the gradient (pink centre with black border) since by observing a scene you'r changing dynamically point of view, it means what is black border fro one point of view are not the same black faces from another point of view.

You can set node-tree with pink at centre of object and black border to be baked, but it would be correctly seen only from specific point of view, and that is not what you are looking for.

### WebGL

I don't have experience with Three.js but it use WebGL so probably it works like Sketchfab ... in this example ground and tree trunks are baked (you already know how to).Tree leaves (spheres) are just simple  Principled BSDF node with Base Color Pink, Metallic 1, Roughness 0.05, Emission Pink

[image]

Sketchfab is able to import and translate into its ecosystem. Textures should be packed and use [naming convensions](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202600873-Materials-and-Textures#textures-auto-pbr) to be assign automatically (but can be uploaded and assign also manually. Bloom is set on Sketchfab site ...

[image]

https://skfb.ly/ovyw8

[image]

### Light Strength

The light difference between Cycles and Eevee is that - Eevee doesn't support mesh light (directly), so in Eevee is your scene light just by light objects, but Cycles render is light by emissive tree material plus by light objects ... that is why cycles looks lit by light more than in Eevee.

Note: Some of your tree normals are orientated inside ... it can generate some issues. To fix the orientation, select your objects, go to edit mode, and press `Shift` + `N` to *Recalculate Normals*.

[image]

Comment: could you explain to me what i am supposed to do? 
change color ramp from black to pink to pink to black?

Comment: @YousufChaudhry ... thanks for edit (it was rejected by Bot due my work on edit at the same time, so I added you extension now. Thanks again for enhancing :)

Comment: @Hawasaki7 I tried to explain with more details .. see if it is clear now :)

Comment: makes sense, thats what i thought about tree leaves that they were changing dynamically, but without it i was getting weird emission, too bright without showing the structure. i will try now to change settings hopefully everything works properly. thanks again

Comment: @Hawasaki7 I don't have experience with Three.js but it use WebGL so probably can be something set out of blender ... like in Sketchfab something like this with Metallic-Emission-Bloom https://skfb.ly/ovyw8

Comment: that is what i am looking for exactly. could you walk me through it?

Comment: I don't think, there is too much say ... WebGL part extended about some info, I'm not sure how much useful :)

Comment: thanks i will try  it out